# how to change ng-keypress to ng-change function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here I have a text box. In that field There is a validation that need to allow only numeric,alphabets and spanish characters. For that I found a function in javascript. That function is in ng-keypress, I want to change it to ng-change. If I change, The function is not firing.

How to change the function to ng-change.

**JSP code:-**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-keypress="getPatternForAlphebet($event,$index)">
```

**script code:-**

```
 $scope.getPatternForAlphebet = function(event,rowIndex){   
        var key = key || event.which;
        if($scope.documentTypeNumber==1 || $scope.documentTypeNumber ==2){
            if ((key > 64 && key < 91)|| (key > 159 && key < 166) || (key > 96 && key < 123) || (key == 165) ||(key == 32)
                    || (key == 164) || (key == 130) || (key == 181) || (key == 144) || (key == 214) ||
                    (key == 224) ||(key == 233) || (key == 8) || (key == 241) || (key == 209)) {
            }else{
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }else if($scope.documentTypeNumber==6){
            if ((key > 64 && key < 91)|| (key > 159 && key < 166) || (key > 96 && key < 123) || (key == 165) ||(key == 32) ||
                    (key == 59) || (key == 164) || (key == 58) || (key == 46) || (key == 44) || (key == 38) ||
                    (key == 34) || (key == 130) || (key == 181) || (key == 144) || (key == 214) ||
                    (key == 224) ||(key == 233) || (key == 8) || (key == 241) || (key == 209)) {
            }else{
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Hi @Rakesh, the $event is not an available property for ng-change. you mush have to find some other solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use a directive instead. Please find the following code update it as you need, I hope this will help. Please add the key codes for Backspace and delete in both. Thank you

```
<input type="text"  ng-model="name" documentvalue="{{documentTypeNumbe}}" filtered-character>

directive('filteredCharacter', function () {
  return function (scope, element, attrs) {

    element.bind("keydown paste", function (event) {
      //console.log($.inArray(event.which,keyCode));
      var keyCode = [];
      if (attrs.documentvalue == 1 || attrs.documentvalue == 2) {
        keyCode = [65, 91, 159]; // Please add all the required key codes
      } else if (attrs.documentvalue == 6) {
        keyCode = [67, 93, 161]; // Please add all the required key codes
      }
      if ($.inArray(event.which, keyCode) === -1) {
        scope.$apply(function () {
          scope.$eval(attrs.filteredCharacter);
          event.preventDefault();
        });
        event.preventDefault();
      }

    });
  };
});
```

Comment: this is fine but I have conditions like if($scope.documentTypeNumber==1 || $scope.documentTypeNumber ==2){}esle{}

Comment: Where you get this $scope.documentTypeNumber??

Comment: angular controller

Comment: So you get the $scope.documentTypeNumber before entering the characters inside the <input> tag ??

Comment: directive is not firing

Comment: great answer. but it is not working when I paste the word

Comment: Add 'paste' and all required actions along with the 'keydown' in the directive code line **element.bind("keydown paste", function (event) {**

Comment: is it possible to add change instead keydown. when I paste the directive is calling but keycode is not comming

Comment: Yes, you can add like this  "keydown paste change". Thank you.

Comment: can we have chat box for a min

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. What is the problem you facing now?

Comment: Here If I paste key which is not coming. Eg:- if I enter 'a' the key code is 65, If I pase the code is not coming

Comment: Sorry, the key of a is 65. You can use this site for key reference https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: yes, I entered by mistake. key which is not coming when I paste

Comment: It is giving the key code when keydown only. if I add paste and change, for them it is not giving key codes

Comment: Alexis Toby any help

Answer (score 1):

`ng-change` must be used with `ng-model`. So, add `ng-model` to  the input field.

Read more about `ng-change` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

**EDIT :**

As  *Alexis Toby* said, `ng-change` does not have `$event`. Remove it. It will work.

Comment: Once see this plunker. It should work.https://plnkr.co/edit/73iVEr2mR0APHMeNgzWp?p=preview

Comment: even Event is not firing

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with plunker?

Comment: this is the plnkr :- https://plnkr.co/edit/O2JgLl1zRUNUnGA9ukL2?p=preview

Comment: Using ng-change, you will not get which key is pressed. So e.which logic will get failed.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the same the function using "ng-keydown". Follow the link to this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5SkBvSSwHQb53e5bY0Ua?p=preview)

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-keydown="getPatternForAlphebet($event,$index)">
```

Comment: did you try using "ng-keydown", though?