# ng-change event is not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here I have ng-keypress function for a text box. And that function is firing when keypress, if I change from ng-keypress to ng-change that event is not firing.

here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/O2JgLl1zRUNUnGA9ukL2?p=preview).

```
$scope.getPatternForAlphebet = function(event,rowIndex){   
        var key = key || event.which;
            if ((key > 64 && key < 91)|| (key > 159 && key < 166) || (key > 96 && key < 123) || (key == 165) ||(key == 32)
                    || (key == 164) || (key == 130) || (key == 181) || (key == 144) || (key == 214) ||
                    (key == 224) ||(key == 233) || (key == 8) || (key == 241) || (key == 209)) {
            }else{
                event.preventDefault();
            }
    };
```

How can I change from ng-keypress to ng-change.

Comment: Hi @Rakesh, please refer the updated answer I given for your post in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44537376/how-to-change-ng-keypress-to-ng-change-function

Answer (score 0):

Its firing for ng-change as well in the plunker. But ng-change will  not pass the $event into the handler. So you need to re-write the logic. But Function calling is happening. ng-change is not a directive for handling the change event but is actually instead notified when ngModelController.$setViewValue() is called and the value changes

Comment: can you please help me regarding this